# webpack-encore .setPublicPath relative ignored

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I try set relative path to assets

```
 .setPublicPath('build/')
```

but when compile i get

```
 The value passed to setPublicPath() should *usually* start with "/" or be a full URL (http://...). If you're not sure, then you should probably change your public path and make this message disappea
```

and generate links

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

and get

```
<script src="/build/runtime.js" defer></script>
<script src="/build/vendors~app.js" defer></script>
<script src="/build/app.js" defer></script>
```

I need build/ not /build/

I have server with folder based apps so why cannot setup patch like I want. I know that when app use routing /aa/bb/cc this stops working. But this app in one page. one link all request is ajax.

Like in message "should *usually* start with "/" " should must by replaced we add / because this is better for you...

Comment: Relative paths do not make much sense in this context. What do you want the URL to be relative to?

Comment: I add update, because i must have relative links. I create app for exist server enviroment. It use folder based links. so im in /myapp/ so /build search for assets in main host directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found working solution

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html

```
.setOutputPath('public/build/')
- .setPublicPath('/build')
+ // this is your *true* public path
+ .setPublicPath('/myAppSubdir/build')
+ // this is now needed so that your manifest.json keys are still `build/foo.js`
+ // (which is a file that's used by Symfony's `asset()` function)
+ .setManifestKeyPrefix('build')
```

i read myAppSubdir from env and is almost dynamic.